# Transparent edit text view is different in 2.3 version and 4.2 version

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm struggling with a small problem, my question is I am using a transparent edit text view in the design part, in 4.2 version android device looking fine well and good, if I check that same edit text in 2.3 version and below version showing a black coloured edit text. this is my edit text code.

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/name"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_margin="5dip"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:alpha="0.3"
          android:background="@drawable/reg_edittext"
          android:ellipsize="end"
          android:ems="10"
          android:lines="1"
          android:scrollHorizontally="true"
          android:singleLine="true"
          android:textColor="#ffffff" />
```

here is my reg_edittext

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--  res/drawable/rounded_edittext.xml -->
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp"  >
<solid android:color="#000000" />
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="5dp"
             android:bottomLeftRadius="5dp"
             android:topLeftRadius="5dp"
             android:topRightRadius="5dp"/>
</shape>
```

showing a black coloured edit text in 2.3 version, in 4.2 showing transparent. answer me I would like to view same transparent in 2.3 version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[please check the link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#ALPHA)

```
 android:alpha="0.3" this alpha property is added in API level 14. So in the previous version it map looks different depends on devices.
```

Try to change the backgroud solid color as transparent it may help you out.

```
android:color="#000000" to transparent color range- #FF000000 to #00000000
```

Answer (score 3):

Although @Sri's answer is mostly correct, it's not complete. You're seeing an opaque black background because the following attribute wasn't added until API level **11** (Android 3.0):

- [`android:alpha="0.3"`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#alpha)

Fortunately, you can add transparency to colors. To make the background color translucent, with the same 0.3/30% alpha value, change the `solid` declaration to:

```
<solid android:color="#4C000000" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You must specify alpha also while specifying the color if you want to give any transparency for the same. So the total color value should be in the format #AARRGGBB where AA - is the alpha color value (00 - transperant, FF- opaque)  , RR - red color, GG - green color, BB- Blue color. In your case to get complete transperant background gou have to specify like this:

```
android:textColor="#00000000"
```